# Top N Sort in Power BI

Tags: report, powerbi, dashboard

I am creating a report in Power BI and I want to present the data from a column sorted by another column. Multi-row Card is the best visualisation that can show the text of that first column that I was writing about.

I have tried to filter the shown data by using Top N option. Top N by value (value that was the column that I want to be taken into consideration when presenting the data from the first column)

I want the list to be presented in the following order :

```
Milo Can
Milo Regular
Nescafe 3 In 1
Milo 3 In 1
Nescafe 2 In 1
Nescafe RTD
Milo 3 in 1
Nestea
Milo UHT Breakfast
```

as this is the ranking based on the other column :

```
731    Milo Can
1837   Milo Regular
2943   Nescafe 3 In 1
4049   Milo 3 In 1
5155   Nescafe 2 In 1
6261   Nescafe RTD
7367   Milo 3 in 1
8473   Nestea
9579   Milo UHT Breakfast
```

Can someone please help me with that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example below:
Add the title to the values of the grid. Now go to the Filters and select Top N (not Basic). give the numbers of items you want to show and set as By value the rank field. Do not forget to apply the filter.

[image]